# Age-restricted videos - Is "media:rating" sufficient?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm using Youtube's API to determine whether a video has been age-restricted. I've read that looking at the value of the **media:rating** tag will do just that.

However, when testing it out with [Battlefield 3: End Game Launch Trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wo0O-DCQJeo), a video which is preceded by a Content Warning, I see that there is no "media:rating" tag in the [metadata](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/wo0O-DCQJeo?v=2).

Is simply checking **media:rating** insufficient when determining the video's age restriction? Is there another tag to check? Or am I missing something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

That's the only exposed attribute in v2 of the API that holds information about restrictions. I've periodically seen videos like this, where they are age-restricted but the media:rating tag is missing (I'm guessing it's likely that the public front-end uses a different, unexposed attribute for determining how it restricts the videos). You might want to report the video so the developers can look into why it doesn't have that metadata.

Related link:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/4Bzbr_uLkdA